# Jquery DateTime picker restriction

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I have a problem here in jQuery DateTime picker

```
 $('#eta_add').datetimepicker({
    ampm: true
 });
```

I've Googled how to disable future dates and it works. The problem is how to restrict the date with the maximum time. Example:

```
2014-03-10 23:59:59
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

```
$('#eta_add').datetimepicker({
    ampm: true
    hour: 23,
    minute: 59,
    second: 59,
});
```

define the time manually using these parameters: `hour`, `minute` and `second`